# HTML 5 Data List / PHP

Tags: php, html, autocomplete, datalist

I have a table named 'users' and the fields are `user_id` and `name` 
Im using a datalist tag to serve as a autocomplete and I wonder 
how to associate the id field whenever a user picks at the autosuggest part

```
<input type='text' name='srch' id='srch' list='datalist1' />
<datalist id='datalist1'>
    <option value='<?php echo $name; ?>' />
<datalist />
```

Comment: you can use jquery autocomplete plugin... search for it. =)

Comment: i guess i'll try it sir and post when its done :D thank you

Comment: It's easy to use... cheerio.. =)

Comment: http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-autocomplete-country-example/
check for it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion dude